# how to use zurb foundation along side bootstrap in Laravel Vue?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, zurb-foundation, laravel-vue

I have a template built in zurb foundation for a sub-domain, i want to use foundation along side bootstrap in my laravel Vue app, entire site uses bootstrap but a subdomain template requires foundation. i have looked for solution but all of them are telling to remove bootstrap. any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixing different CSS frameworks will not work as both manipulate the DOM, use the same class names and CSS classes in components and so on. You would have to prefix everything, encapsulate it and so on.